# How to extract the canvas animation creator/trigger function from a website?

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is a canvas: https://www.docker.com/#canvasCircle

[image: theImage]

I am thinking to use the function/images that creates this canvas. You can see that the circles are created first and then there is a ribbon like movement of the line from first canvas to last.

I have been trying to find either the images or the animation function. But couldn't. I would like to modify it and use it for my website.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as a front-end , I would use Photo Shop. Transfer everything to layers and extract the images. Than with css or Jquery , you can add :focus or :hover to make them pop or animate them. Not sure exactly what you want with it. With css you can also use transform etc. Hope this helps. It would help to know what exactly do you want the images to do so we can think of a code.

Comment: I know canvas. But if you visit the above link, there is an animation of a ribbon moving around those circle images. The canvas itself can be saved as a image. But not the animation. So I would like to get the code behind that animation i.e, the code that created the canvas. Note: I am not new to canvas or css or html.

Comment: Than you should use SVG. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial  ... Check this site out . Maybe you find what you need :)

Comment: No offence created. But, Your answer is irrelevant. I want to extract the function code block of the canvas being generated. Anyway thanks for answering.